# After form completion redirect to temporary view, then redirect to another

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, redirect

I've got a simple controller:

```
 //Begin MakeBooking
        public ActionResult MakeBooking()
        {
            return View(new Appointment() { Date = DateTime.Now });
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult MakeBooking(Appointment appt)
        {
            //repository stuff
            return View("Completed",appt);
        }
        //End MakeBooking

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

I'm looking for an idiomatic way to show the user the Completed view once the form has been posted, say for five seconds, and then redirect back to, say, Index/Home.  Does .NET provide any native way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does .NET provide any native way to do this?

No, But you can certainly achieve your requirement using jQuery setTimeOut function. As an example please find below script -

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            window.location.href = "@Url.Action("SubmitTag")"
        }, 5000);
    });
</script>
```

Above script will make the browser request to SubmitTag action. 5000 is the wait time in milliseconds before which the URL change code will fire.

You need to have this kind of script on your Completed view.

Comment: It wasn't too long after I asked this that I realized that it wouldn't make any sense to have a server redirect after the server had already rendered the view.